# How to stop my script execution after certain time

Tags: unix

for example my script starts at 9:00 AM and it should stop its execution at 11:00 AM, with 2 hrs time limit. Is there any way to achieve this ? Appreciate everyones response.

Comment: Please add more detail. On which platform? How do you currently start the script?

Answer (score 1):

If you slip in something like

```
THIS=$$
(sleep 7200 && kill $THIS) &
```

at the top of your script, that should do the trick.

Another possibility...install coreutils, then use the `timeout` (or `gtimeout`) command:

https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html

Comment: Another thought...if your concern is, for instance, that you are running this script from cron, and you don't want subsequent executions to overlap, you might consider using a command-line utility like lockfile or flock to prevent overlap...